# Uncaught reference error: require is not defined in React native 0.59.5

Tags: javascript, react-native

After upgrading to React Native 0.59.5, I am getting:

```
Uncaught reference error: require is not defined
```

babel.config.js

```js
module.exports = {
  presets: [
    'module:metro-react-native-babel-preset',
    '@babel/preset-flow',
    [
      '@babel/preset-env',
      {
        targets: {
          esmodules: true,
        },
      },
    ],
    'airbnb',
  ],
  plugins: [
    'transform-class-properties',
    ['@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators', { legacy: true }]
  ],
};
```

**Node**: 8.10.0
**npm**: 5.6.0
**React native**: 0.59.5

[image]

Comment: Check this, if you haven't already: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/22522

Comment: I do not even have `env: { development }`, is there anything else that I should change?

Answer (score 0):

Try to do the following babel config and don't forget to install the required libraries if missing:

```
module.exports = {
  presets: ["@babel/preset-flow", "module:metro-react-native-babel-preset"],
  plugins: [
    ["@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators", { legacy: true }],
    ["@babel/plugin-transform-flow-strip-types"],
    ["babel-plugin-react-native-nodeify-hack"],
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import",
    [
      "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties",
      {
        loose: true
      }
    ],
    "@babel/plugin-transform-regenerator",
    [
      "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime",
      {
        helpers: false,
        regenerator: true
      }
    ]
  ]
};
```

Then you can clean the project with this command (IOS Only)

```
watchman watch-del-all && rm -rf node_modules && npm install && rm -rf $TMPDIR/haste-map-react-native-packager-* && rm -rf $TMPDIR/react-native-packager-cache-* && rm -rf $TMPDIR/metro-bundler-cache-* && rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData && pod deintegrate ios/{YOUR_PROJECT}.xcodeproj && rm -rf ./ios/Pods && pod install --project-directory=./ios/ && rm -f /ios/build && npm cache verify
```

And then re-run the project

```
react-native run-ios
```

Hopefully this will resolve your issue

Comment: Thanks will try that and post the result.

Comment: Don't forget to change  pod deintegrate ios/{YOUR_PROJECT}.xcodeproj according to your project. Wish it will works for you at the end